# Doxygen reference link failed when path is directory

Tags: html, doxygen

I am using doxygen for C++ project document generation, using [reference link](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_reflinks) `@ref` in `.md` files. Some `@ref` genereates real hyperlinks in html page, while other won't (when `.md` file's realpath is deeper).

To reproduce:

- Doxygen version: 1.9.2 (from github repo, the latest commit)
- System: ubuntu 20.04
- Project structure:

```
- docs
  - root.md
  - Doxyfile
- src
  - rok_core
    - doc
      - test.md
    - do
      - test.md
```

Doxyfile:

```
...
INPUT: root.md \
../src/rok_core/doc/test.md \
../src/rok_core/do/test.md \
...
```

`doc/root.md`:

```
Rok {#mainpage}
===

- @ref test
- @ref test2
```

`src/rok_core/doc/test.md`:

```
test {#test}
=====
```

`src/rok_core/do/test.md`:

```
test2 {#test2}
=====
```

The expected behavior: both test and test2 are links in mainpage (generated from root.md), but actually `test2` is link but `test` is not link.

**OK, finally I figure out its my fault. My provided example can generated all @ref links. I mis-write EXCLUDE that covers my doc directory, leading to this silly question. So sorry.**

Comment: from github repo, the latest commit is a moving target, always use the full information of `doxygen -v`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information in the issue and after correcting the `INPUT` tag to:

```
INPUT= root.md \
../src/rok_core/doc/test.md \
../src/rok_core/do/test.md
```

(rest of the Doxyfile is left empty).
I started doxygen (1.9.2 (97cb0de4dab1f9eb77325f7ee9f46dcaed8b0c69)) and the result is:

[image]

where both `test`s are links (to the right place).